# Cherrypy creating hundreds of thousands of sessions a day for a site recieving 500 average unique users. Should it be handled the following way?

Tags: session, cherrypy

Having trouble with many sessions files being created sometimes as high as 400,000!  I thought I could detect if a session variable is not None using a get but strangely checking a session variable actually creates a session file:

```
if(cherrypy.session.get('Something')):
```

I know a session file is create for every request but if I don't run cherrypy.session.get the session file gets deleted.  If you run the following code on Cherrypy 3.2.4 after requesting 127.0.0.1:8080/main
the session file is deleted.

```
import cherrypy

class Root:
    def main(self):
        return 'Howdy'
    main.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True,
                        'tools.sessions.storage_type': "File",
                        'tools.sessions.storage_path': 'sessions',
                        'tools.sessions.timeout': 1440
               })

cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),'/')
```

However executing this code will create session variable that will timeout in 1440 mins.

```
import cherrypy

class Root:
    def main(self):
        if(cherrypy.session.get('Something')):
            asdf = 'asdf'
        return 'Howdy'
    main.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True,
                        'tools.sessions.storage_type': "File",
                        'tools.sessions.storage_path': 'adf',
                        'tools.sessions.timeout': 1440
               })

cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),'/')
```

So How can I check if a user has a session variable without creating a server side session file that is not deleted?

Any help would be appreciated,
Andrew

Comment: Why are you getting so many sessions? You are not serving static files with CherryPy and sessions on, are you?

Comment: No - nginx is serving my static content.  We believe these are bots generating the excess sessions.

Comment: When a normal user makes first request, do they get a fixed session id, as they don't have the cookie? How is bot request different from normal user first request?

Comment: yes at first they are assigned a fixed id and a cookie is written then they are redirected and if the server can read the cookie value their assigned a real session.  Bots will always have a fixed session id however that portion is implemented now and I believe the run away sessions are from bots that don't accept cookies or curl request not accepting cookies and the like.

Comment: It looks like it could work, but direct URLs won't (users will have to be redirected to home page, right?) and, more important, the logic is somewhat obscure, so it can lead to maintenance problems in the future. My personal opinion aside, why are the sessions not getting cleaned up?

Comment: Regular user's sessions are being cleaned up however I believe requests not accepting cookies aren't being cleaned.  I will redirect the user back the original page they request but will know if they will accept cookies.  I know I will have to maintain this each time I update an affected library but our site dogs when Linux needs to search 400,000 sessions for the correct one.

Comment: Sessions get cleaned just fine for me regardless of the cookies. So you should look into that.

Comment: It looks as though checking to seeing if a session variable exists cherrypy creates a session.  executing:    if(cherrypy.session.get('Reminders')):  does create a file session.  So how do you detect if the current user has a session?

Comment: A new session is always created unless there is a valid session cookie with some associated data. However, as I said before, sessions eventually get deleted whether they have data or not. If they don't for you, I guess you should post some code that doesn't work.

Comment: @jwalker updated my question with better examples.

Comment: I quickly looked at CP source code, and you seem to be right about `get()` creating a session. Going to run the code and see if they get cleaned up, though. Should I run it on Windows or Linux? Does timeout value matter, gonna set it to few mins?

Comment: timeouot value does need to be set for the 1440 for our website.  Running on CentOS 6.  Looking into something like this to test if the session is created.   def _check_for_session(self=None):
        return os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sessions/session-' + cherrypy.session.id))

Comment: Expired sessions are removed for me with your code, so not sure what your issue is. You can use `cherrypy.session.originalid` to see if current request did send a session cookie.

Comment: so you're saying the sessions get cleaned up after timeout?

Comment: Yes. I might have had one stuck but I did something wrong which probably affected it.

Comment: FYI, I set `tools.sessions.timeout` and `tools.sessions.clean_freq` to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to work.  Since executing cherrypy.session.get('_cp_Email') causes a permanent session I found a way to check if a session file exists.  When a permanent session exists there is a  "session-" + cherrypy.session.id file (one without a .lock extension).  This code checks for that...

```
def check_for_session(self=None):
    return os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sessions/session-' + cherrypy.session.id))


def index(self=None):
    if(check_for_session() and cherrypy.session.get('_cp_Email')):
        Email = cherrypy.session[('_cp_Email']
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I tried something like: if(cherrypy.session.originalid != None and cherrypy.session.get('Something') == False): but then it doesn't create a permanent session for real users.  But add an answer if you have working code - it may help someone.